ANALYZE command not write data into hive metastore
Good day,
In SIT, I have manually create a hive table.
Follow by manually create a partition on it.
Then I copy the bucket file from other table and put inside the partition.
At this moment, if I run select statement, I getting 0 result, I believe this is normal because data havent write to metastore.
Then I run the following commands:
ANALYZE TABLE raw_zone_sit.jxtemp PARTITION (dl_created_yr='2023', dl_created_mth='12') 
COMPUTE STATISTICS;

After I run this command, I able to select data from my table.
After that I apply the same way in production, but I am still getting empty result.
Currently I am trying to recover all the metastore in production, this is because 1 of the person accidently delete all the metastore in production. Thus now I am trying to recover on it.
For your information, parquet tables working fine. But I have some ORC tables also, now pending ORC table to resolve.
Please help.
